# Azure Logic App FTP Create file fails with MaxRequestCountReached

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps

I am creating an Azure Logic App that will create a new file (from HTTP body content of about 5KB) on an FTP server.

Here is the FTP Create File code snippet:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "host": {
            "connection": {
                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['ftp']['connectionId']"
            }
        },
        "method": "post",
        "body": "@body('Provider_Post')",
        "path": "/datasets/default/files",
        "queries": {
            "folderPath": "/",
            "name": "filename_@{utcNow()}.xml",
            "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
        },
        "authentication": "@parameters('$authentication')"
    },
    "runtimeConfiguration": {
        "contentTransfer": {
            "transferMode": "Chunked"
        }
    }
}
```

This step takes really long (32 minutes) and then fails with following error:

```
MaxRequestCountReached. The maximum number of requests allowed '1000' was not sufficient to upload the entire content. Uploaded content length: '2378'. Total content length: '4877'.
```

The file appears on the FTP server but only 2380 bytes from the **end** of the file is there.

What does this error mean and how to fix it? 5KB shouldn't be too much of data. Is this something about the FTP server? I can send the file with FileZilla without problems.

I even tested this so that I created another step (before the failing one) that will send the HTTP content statusCode (so, just "200") to a new file and it writes it, succesfully, in one second.

Comment: What's your run history detail? Is the HTTP body content length too long? And your filename with @{utcNow()}, this default format name won't be allowed to created. So you could try with test_@{utcNow('yyyyMMddHHmmss')}.xml

Comment: What do you mean by run history detail? The error message is there and the duration was mentioned. Size of the step is 5637 bytes. The filename is not a problem as I create the smaller file with same type of filename.

Comment: 5KB couldn't be restricted. So did you set the [Allow chunking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTmO0.png) on.

Comment: Allow chunking is on. It didn't work with Allow chunking off either.

Comment: I added more info. There is 2380 bytes of the file from **end** of the file in the FTP server.

Comment: Not that I suggest this as a solution in full but, could you test with a SFTP upload connection instead?

Comment: @AdAstra the FTP server does not support SFTP but as I went to check this I noticed the Binary Transport checkbox in the API connection parameters. It wasn't enabled. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this misbehaved was that I had disabled Binary Transport in the ftp API connection settings.

When I enabled the Binary Transport checkbox, it wrote the file in seconds.